# Commands delimited by `\{`, `\|`, `\langle`, etc

Tags: xparse, delimiters, physics

The `xparse` package offers the possibility to define commands delimited by single special start/end character. This can be very useful, for instance it is used a lot in the `physics` package. I was wondering if it would be possible to also define commands delimited by other structures such as `\{`, `\|` or `\langle`. Curiously, it seems to *almost* work out of the box:

> [image]

It appears that the braces get recognized correctly, however some additional characters are inserted. Why is this happening & is there a way to patch it?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testA}{d\{\}}{ \IfNoValueTF{#1}{error}{(#1)} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\testB}{d\|\|}{ \IfNoValueTF{#1}{error}{(#1)} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\testC}{d\langle\rangle}{ \IfNoValueTF{#1}{error}{(#1)} }
\begin{document}
$ \testA\{X\} \testB\|X\| \testC\langle X\rangle $
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the `d` in your commands for?

Comment: @Bernard `d` means an argument `d`elimited by two tokens in `xparse`

Comment: Oh! yes. I had forgotten this way to specify arguments in `xparse`. But what do you want to really produce with such unusual delimiters?

Comment: The documentation says `d⟨char1⟩⟨char2⟩` and control sequences are not really supported.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The argument specifiers `d` and `D` should be followed by two *characters*, not arbitrary tokens.

If you enable a check that should always be used when testing programs, like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[log-declarations]{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testA}{d\{\}}{ \IfNoValueTF{#1}{error}{(#1)} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\testB}{d\|\|}{ \IfNoValueTF{#1}{error}{(#1)} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\testC}{d\langle\rangle}{ \IfNoValueTF{#1}{error}{(#1)} }
\begin{document}
$ \testA\{X\} \testB\|X\| \testC\langle X\rangle $
\end{document}
```

you get the warnings

```latex
LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\{' for the command '\testA' should be a
(LaTeX3)        single character.

LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\}' for the command '\testA' should be a
(LaTeX3)        single character.

LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\|' for the command '\testB' should be a
(LaTeX3)        single character.

LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\|' for the command '\testB' should be a
(LaTeX3)        single character.

LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\langle ' for the command '\testC' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.

LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\rangle ' for the command '\testC' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.
```

Possibly these should be actual errors. The behavior in these cases is not predictable.

See https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/368