# Lots of warnings with the physics package with the last version of expl3

Tags: expl3, physics

Everything worked fine till I use Texlive Utility to update some packages. Then I get a lots of warnings. Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
MWE
\end{document}
```

and here is the result in the console window

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/physics/physics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
)

LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\big ' for the command '\@quantity' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\Big ' for the command '\@quantity' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\bigg ' for the command '\@quantity'
(LaTeX3)        should be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\Bigg ' for the command '\@quantity'
(LaTeX3)        should be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\big ' for the command '\@braces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\Big ' for the command '\@braces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\bigg ' for the command '\@braces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\Bigg ' for the command '\@braces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\big ' for the command '\fbraces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\Big ' for the command '\fbraces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\bigg ' for the command '\fbraces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\Bigg ' for the command '\fbraces' should
(LaTeX3)        be a single character.


LaTeX3 Warning: Argument delimiter '\ket ' for the command '\bra' should be a
(LaTeX3)        single character.

) (./MWE.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1{/usr/local/t
exlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./MWE.aux) )</usr/l
ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/loc
al/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 15935 bytes).
SyncTeX written on MWE.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on MWE.log
```

Does anybody have a solution to make these warnings disappear?

Comment: I don't get them in texlive 2020 pretest (which has a newer expl3).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how do I get the pretest version?

Comment: https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Everything works fine now with the pretest version that I discovered thanks to you! I can keep updating till the new release. Happy with that since there are important packages with some bugs annoying for me (like import.sty). Can you make your comment an answer then I can accept it and give you upvote?

Comment: @brunoh `physics` is know for abusing `xparse`.

Comment: @egreg this is clear. When I have time I will use other solutions available. It is time somebody re-code this (very useful) package from scratch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of control sequence tokens (such as `\big`) was not supported in `xparse` (see [`latex3/latex3#367`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/367) and [`latex3/latex3#368`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/368)), only character tokens were allowed, and an explicit warning (the one you see) should show up when non-character tokens were used.

However due to a small bug, this warning was silenced and wrong output as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529859/134574) would be produced. By the final days of TL'19 this warning got reactivated and then with TL'19 you see these warnings (also related to that change, this warning: [`latex3/babel#52`](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/52)). Except for the warning, the behaviour didn't change, so the output is the same as you'd get before.

For TL'20, `xparse` was extended to support (most) control sequence tokens as argument delimiters, so that warning was removed and the code should work correctly.

Comment: This very clear explanation is accepted as an answer!